# This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^17.0.0, but Angular version 11.0.9 was found instead. Getting Error

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material, frontend, angular-cli

[package.json file (https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5r3q.png)

> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer zone.js@"~0.10.3" from @angular/core@11.0.9
> npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
> npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~11.0.9" from the root project
> npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"^11.0.2" from @angular-material-extensions/select-country@4.3.0
> npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-material-extensions/select-country
> npm ERR!     @angular-material-extensions/select-country@"^4.0.3" from the root project
> npm ERR!   2 more (@angular/cdk, @angular/common)
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
> npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
> npm ERR!
> ]

Comment: Hi, just read the error message you will understand what's the problem: `Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer zone.js@"~0.10.3"` look the version of zone.js you have in your devDependencies. Error message are there for a reason, you should read them :)

Answer (score 0):

You must be using version cli 11.0.9. So try using:

npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@11.0.9 --force